# A request of a journal theorem

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I am reading the paper [*Groups whose proper subgroups are finite-by-nilpotent*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01781552) by Maoqian Xu and he has some references that I can't find. Does somebody have (B. Bruno, On p-groups with nilpotent-by-finite proper subgroups, theorem **3.8**) and ( V. V. Beljaev and N. F. Sesekin, On infinite groups of Miller-Moreno type **5.1**)? I need these to understand some proofs in his paper.
Thank you

Comment: the journal that I am reading is by Maqqian Xu (Groups whose proper subgroups are finite-by-nilpotent) and he uses theorems from Bruno and Beljaev in roofs, those theorems are used in proofs and I can't find them

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01781552

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro here is the link

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect what I believe you are asking. Let me know if you think the new version is not correct. I'll delete my comments in an hour or two (or tomorrow, if I forget to do so today).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro that's exactly what I want to say, thank you very much

Comment: You can download the file [here](https://filezemp.univ-st-etienne.fr/on2vdcqv). Say me if everything is OK.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have this file but I 'ont have files I have set up there papers by B. Bruno and by V. V. Beljaev and N. F. Sesekin

Comment: All right,  I had not read with sufficient attention...